# Recommend a book to learn how to accompany on piano

Tags: piano, accompaniment

For example, I know chords: G, E, C, D, etc. I want to play good piano accompaniment with these chords (not just bang them on a strong beat) and sing. Can you recommend me a good book where I can learn how to accompaniment with piano?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to Music.SE! Unfortunately book recommendations are off topic here, but feel free to talk about this in our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room)!